# Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31. while reading from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I am using an xml file to read the contents and display it in a tree view list with checkboxes. The condition for this is that the contents should be displayed on the basis of what the user selected in combo box. Suppose the user selected 2 in combo box, then the treeview list should display the contents of 2(from xml file). I have tried like:

```
private void pjctsel_cmbbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var xmldoc = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\\test.xml");
    var str = XElement.Parse(xmldoc);
    cmbbox_val = pjctsel_cmbbox.SelectedIndex.ToString();
***  var res = str.Elements(cmbbox_val).Where(x => x.Element("general").Value.Equals(cmbbox_val)).ToList();
    MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
}
cmbbox_val = user selected value from combobox.
```

The xmlfile content is:

```
<serv>
    <general name="one">    
    <server name="oneone">
        <service name="1143"/>
        <service name="1142"/>
    </server>
</general>
<general name="two">        
    <server name ="twoone">
        <service name="2143"/>
        <service name="2142"/>
    </server>
</general>
</serv>
```

In my c# code, where I marked *** I am getting the following exception "Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31."

Googled it, but I could find only those starting their xml files with tag string 1.

Any ideas on this?

Any thoughts would be really appreciated..

**EDIT:**

My combo box has values like one,two.

What I am trying is that if the user selects the value two in combo box, then my application needs to check for an entry with the name two in the xml file and if found any match, then the "server name" node and "service name"nodes corresponding to two, must be displayed in the treeview list.

Hope this makes sense..

Comment: @Adriano:Iam just reading that file..not intended to write any contents from my application..

Comment: You still need to know the encoding of the xml file and read the file with that encoding.

Comment: jctsel_cmbbox.SelectedIndex returns a Integer. 1.ToString() <> "one"; 1.ToString == "1"

Comment: Note that you can _edit_ the question. Clarify what's in the combobox and what should happen. Make sure the data's match.

Comment: @HenkHolterman:Question edited..Please see EDIT part

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Why?But these values are displayed in that treeview list when I am not using a combo box..

Comment: No, sorry, I was off by the indenting. It is OK.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Any idea now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmbbox_val = pjctsel_cmbbox.SelectedIndex.ToString();   // SelectedIndex is an integer

var res = str
            .Elements(cmbbox_val)                      // so this will fail
            .Where(x => x.Element("general")
            .Value.Equals(cmbbox_val)).ToList();
```

This might work:

```
cmbbox_val = pjctsel_cmbbox.SelectedItem.ToString();   // or SelectedItem.SomeProperty
```

---

But I also note that you are looking for `cmbbox_val` 2 times and that `Element("general")` already is the root of your XML. So this can't work but we don't have the information to fix it.

---

After the edit:

> 1. My combo box has values like one,two.
> 2. needs to check for an entry with the name two in the xml file
> 3. then the "server name" node and "service name"nodes must be displayed in the treeview list.

Step 1) and 2)

```
var str = XElement.Parse(xmldoc);
IEnumerable<XElement> generals = str
       .Elements("general")
       .Where(g => g.Attribute("name") == cmbbox_val);
```

and because that result is hierarchical, I would use it with  `foreach()` instead of Linq, like so:

```
foreach(var general in generals)  // probably only 1
{
   foreach (var server in general.Elements("server"))
   {
       string serverName = server.Attribute("name").value;

       foreach(var service  in server.Elements("service"))
       {
           // etc
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: But even this too is failing..in my case..the exception which i recieved is no more a problem..but it is not displaying the contents of what I selected in combo box..can you please put on a solution for that, if you know how to..

Comment: No, I don't have a clue. What values are in your combobox?

Comment: some string values..the server names of xml file

Comment: It has the file names? Then why is it in `.Value.Equals(cmbbox_val)` ?

Comment: Some string values is not a good answer: When the exception is thrown move your mouse cursor over the `cmbbox_val` name and see *exactly* what's in there.

Comment: means: _"some string values..the server names of xml file"_

Comment: @CosminPrund: Now no exceptions thrown..but it is not displaying the contents of the combobox value from that xml file

Comment: @HenkHolterman:In this step, Where(g => g.Attribute("name") == cmbbox_val);
I am getting an error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute' and 'string'"

What I mean by step number 2 is that whatever the user selects in combo box that value should be checked in the xml file. If the user selects two, then it should check for the value two in xml file.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN [XElement.Elements()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) takes as a parameter a string that represents the name of the element to be selected. Names can't begin with `1` and you get that error because you're passing `cmbbox_val` for `Elements()`.

You are using that `cmbbox_val` for both the `Value.Equals` and as the node selector: I bet it contains the `string` `"1143"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing an `integer` as `XElement` `name`. The name should not begin with a digit. Possible mistake is that in your code you pass combobox.`SelectedIndex`. If you have configured the combobox properly(i.e 1,"one"  2,"two) you should pass combobox.`SelectedValue`. If you don't fill the value list of the combobox  you can change the code as:

```
private void pjctsel_cmbbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var xmldoc = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\\test.xml");
        var str = XElement.Parse(xmldoc);
        string cmbbox_val = pjctsel_cmbbox.SelectedIndex==0 ? "one" : "two";
        var res = str.Elements(cmbbox_val).Where(x => x.Element("general").Value.Equals(cmbbox_val)).ToList();
        MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
    }
```